# Using Protocol for Asynchronous Response

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, delegates, protocols

I have a post request in my Helper class, and on receiving response, I want to set up a delegate and a function to run on my ViewController. However, as this is an asynchronous task I felt suspicious if it's definitely going to make it.

I tried setting up a protocol and delegate however I couldn't setup a proper protocol between my Helper and ViewController

My VC:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, HelperDelegate {

viewDidLoad() {
    let myHelper = Helpers()
    myHelper.HelpersSettingsDelegate = self
}
func update(newUrl: String {
     // save string to db
}
```

My Helper:

```
protocol HelperDelegate : UITableViewController {
    func update(newUrl: String)
}

class Helpers: NSObject {

var HelpersSettingsDelegate : HelperDelegate?


...
 case .Success(let upload, _, _):
        upload.responseJSON { response in
            print("SUCCESS")
            debugPrint(response)
            let new = response.result.value!["success"]

            if let delegate = self.HelperSettingsDelegate {
                 delegate.update(new)
            }

         }
```

> error on `self.HelperSettingsDelegate` Type 'Helpers' has no member 'HelpersSettingsDelegate

So my question is

- Why is not my protocol working?
- Is it safe to use this approach or may some data get lost in between response time (if user leaves the page before running delegate method)?

---

Edit: If I try to use `protocol HelperDelegate { }`, it forces me to use `HelperSettingsDelegate.updateUploadedImageString(Self)`

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to have a reusable component "Helpers" which implements an asynchronous function, want this to be used from within any `UITableViewController` which calls the function `update(_:)` from the table view controller?

IMHO, the best approach would not require to have delegates and protocol for delegates. Just this:

```
class Helper {
    func fetchDataAsync(completion: (result: AnyObject?, error: ErrorType?) -> () {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then, in your table view controller, in any function that uses the helper class, for example in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let helper = Helper(params)
    helper.fetchDataAsync { (data, error) in
        if let data = data {
            let url = ...
            self.update(url)
        }
        // handle error
    }
}
```